# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Python dataclasses error encountered when creating dataclass : TypeError("non-default argument

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm on a fastapi project using sqlalchemy as orm:
I currently have this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Python dataclasses error encountered when creating dataclass for 'User': TypeError("non-default argument 'events' follows default argument"). Please refer to Python dataclasses documentation for additional information. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dcte)

here is my "models.py" file

```
type python

from sqlalchemy import func, Integer, Boolean, DateTime, String, JSON, ForeignKey, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase, relationship
from api.database.basetemplate import BaseTemplate
from typing import Optional, List
from datetime import datetime
# from enum import Enum



class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False, index=True)
    username:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), unique=True, index=True)
    password:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    image_url:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True, default=None)
    nom:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100), default=None)
    prenom:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100), default=None) 
    telephone:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100), default=None)
    is_admin:Mapped[Optional[bool]] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_subscribed:Mapped[Optional[bool]] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    date_subscription:Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=True, default=None)
    date_creation:Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=True, server_default=func.now(), default=datetime.utcnow())
    
    events: Mapped[List["Event"]] = relationship("Event", back_populates="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class Event(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "event"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    nom:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=False)
    image_url:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True, default=None)
    description:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True, default=None)
    contacts:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True, default=None)
    categorie_id:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event_category.id"), nullable=True, default=None)
    type_id:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event_type.id"), nullable=True, default=None)
    lieu:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True, default=None)
    localisation:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=True, default=None)
    date_creation:Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now(), default=datetime.utcnow())
    user_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
     
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship("User", back_populates="events")
    event_category: Mapped["EventCategory"] = relationship("EventCategory", back_populates="event_category")
    event_type: Mapped["EventType"] = relationship("EventType", back_populates="event_type")
    event_dates: Mapped[List["EventDates"]] = relationship("EventDates", back_populates="event", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    event_likes: Mapped[List["EventLikes"]] = relationship("EventLikes", back_populates="event", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    event_comments: Mapped[List["EventComments"]] = relationship("EventComments", back_populates="event", cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class EventLikes(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "event_likes"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    user_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False, default=None)
    event_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event.id"), nullable=False)
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship("User", back_populates="event_likes")
    event: Mapped["Event"] = relationship("Event", back_populates="event_likes")

class EventComments(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "event_comments"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    commentaire:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=False)
    user_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    event_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event.id"), nullable=False)
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship("User", back_populates="event_comments")
    event: Mapped["Event"] = relationship("Event", back_populates="event_comments")


class EventDates(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "event_dates"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    date:Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    heure:Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)

    event_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("event.id"), nullable=False)
    event: Mapped["Event"] = relationship("Event", back_populates="event_dates")


class EventCategory(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "event_category"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)

    events: Mapped[List["Event"]] = relationship("Event", back_populates="event_category", cascade="all, delete-orphan")


class EventType(Base, BaseTemplate):
    __tablename__ = "event_type"
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, init=False)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)

    events: Mapped[List["Event"]] = relationship("Event", back_populates="event_type", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

Help me to solve the problem please

Comment: I t looks like this happens when you try to create a `User` instance.  Please [edit] the question to share the relevant code and the _complete_ error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem came from your "Base" class

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass):
    pass
```

As you inherited it from "MappedAsDataclass", my Event model behaved like a DataClass.
The DataClass takes into account the order in which the arguments are defined (All arguments with a default value come before the one without a default value) Which caused the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Python dataclasses error encountered when creating dataclass for 'Event': Typt argument 'user_id' follows default argument"). Please refer to Python dataclasses documentation for additional ground on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dcte)